# Validating user date entry

Tags: php

Hi everyone I have a form that accepts user date entry in the form

```
dd/mm/yyyy
```

and converts it to US date in the form

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

How can I return an error if the user does not type in the date in the correct format initially? e.g. **12/2012**

This is the code I have so far.

```
// collect values from a form sent with method=get

$uk_date = $_GET["date"];

// convert between date formats

$parts = explode("/", $uk_date, 3);
$us_date = $parts[2] . "-" . $parts[1] . "-" . $parts[0];
echo $us_date.'<br>';
```

Thanks in advance!

I am using PHP btw.

Comment: Look for [strtotime](http://az.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function

Comment: If you are using php 5.3, you could to code with DateTime Class. http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php Try this method http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

Comment: You want to validate date in javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of validating the date, why not just convert the date to the correct format after the form is submitted? That way the user can enter the date in any format they want

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_GET["date"]));
```

Comment: With the above function, the user can type in any format they want, and it will be changed to the format you want, so if a user types in 15 August 2000, 15-08-2000, or whatever, with the above the $date variable will have the format as 2000-08-15

Comment: What about if the user types in an invalid value like **12/2012** or **xxx**?

Comment: How about using a javascript datepicker. Then you can disable the input so they must use the datepicker, and then you can set the format of the datepicker to whatever you want - http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

To stick with the code I have seen I would check to make sure each exploded part of the date is valid, and return an error that includes where the mistake has been made.

Something like the below:

```
$day_error = 'The day has not been entered correctly';
$month_error = 'The month has not been entered correctly';
$year_error = 'The year has not been entered correctly';

if(!isset(part[0]) | $part[0]<1 | $part[0]>31) return $day_error;
if(!isset(part[1]) | $part[1]<1 | $part[1]>12) return $month_error;
if(!isset(part[2]) | strlen($part[2]) != 4) return $year_error;
```

However the other answers I have seen seem a much easier and more robust approach

Comment: Two questions

1) Which part of the code would I put it in?
2) Would it be able to differentiate between the entries of 1/6/2012, 01/06/2012, 1/06/2012 and 01/6/2012?

Comment: Code does not work. I think you forgot the $ on **(!isset(part[0])**... etc